# To find a solution of non-linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab, computational-mathematics, maple, mathematica

Consider the following non-linear PDE:

$u_x^2+u_y^2-u_{xx}-u_{yy}=2a+bz$

where $x,y,z$ are independent variables with $u=u(x,y)$ and $a,b$ are constants.

I am trying to find at least one examples of $u(x,y)$ which satisfies the above PDE.
Can anyone help me to solve the above PDE?
I have also tried to solve the same by Mathematica and Matlab. But I could not succeed.
Also, is there any suggestions/references for solving any non-linear PDE?

Comment: If $u = u(x,y)$ only, how can the PDE in $u$ be equal to a function of another variable $z$ that $u$ doesn't depend on?

Comment: @mattos Are you saying that there is no solution? Because $u$ is a function of $x, y$ only.

Comment: No, I'm saying that if $z$ is a **variable** and $u = u(x,y)$ only depends on the variables $(x,y)$ then your equation doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try some easy things if you ignore some variables.
For example:
$$u(x,y,z)=x\sqrt{2a+bz}$$
may work, at least for $2a+bz>0$.

Furthermore, you can try to solve $v_x^2-v_{xx}=1$ (This can be solved in Wolfram: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28du%2Fdx%29%5E2-d%5E2u%2Fdx%5E2%3D1) and put:
$$
u=(2a+bz)\cdot v
$$
which will work too.